# Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_confirm' not found

Tags: django

I'm setting production environment on EC2. The exactly same code is running on Dev and Prod, but gunicorn (prod) and different settings.py.

It's all working fine, but when a visitor tries to reset password he access the page "password_reset", fill the form with his email but, after submitting, get a 500 error.

When this occour, i'm emailed (admin emails) with this error saying:
"Internal Server Error: /accounts/password_reset/

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password_reset/
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset_confirm' not found. 'auth_password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

What i understand is that "/accounts/password_reset/" is trying to call an "auth_password_reset_confirm" that indeed does not exist (the correct url name is "password_reset_confirm"). But i don't know who is adding this "auth_" before.

I've tried:
1) Confirm on dev and prod that the url name given from django.contrig.auth is "password_reset_confirm"
2) Downloaded server version of django.contrib.auth and confirm no "auth_" is being added to the call.
3) Confirm that i didn't add "auth_" on any url name on my apps.

common_settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #My Apps
    'institutional', #External generic public pages
    'lab', #Internal pages and controllers
    'shop', #External shop pages and controllers
    'account', #Group of dynamics to handle users, members (profile)

    'django.contrib.auth',  #Here just because of django_registration password reset issues if this line was after

    #Third-party Apps
    'django_registration',
    'snowpenguin.django.recaptcha3',
    'pagseguro',
    'polymorphic',
    'django_countries',
    'compressor',

    #Django Default Apps
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Django auth configuration
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

myapp.urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static, staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    #Default admin app urls
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #Account pages
    path('accounts/', include('account.urls')),

    #Pattern to allow lazy translations
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

#Media and images configuration
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

accounts.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views, forms, regbackend
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = [
    #Account necessary views
    path('register/', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=forms.ExtendedRegistrationForm), name='django_registration_register'),
    path('member/', views.member_read, name='accounts.member_read'),
    path('member/update', views.member_update, name='accounts.member_update'),

    #Account pages from Django Auth and django_registration
    path('login/', views.ExtendedLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('django_registration.backends.activation.urls')),
]
```

I realy dont understand what is going on, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a turn around here adding this url to my accounts.url.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
...
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
```

And it's working. But i really need to understand who's calling this page.

Thanks